# Moving from MVC3 to MVC4 session timeout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

We upgraded from MVC3 to MVC4 using the new membership framework.
The session is timing out after 5 minutes.
I tried to set the session to one week, set the sliding session to true, nothing helped.
Godady say they don't support MVC4, but I am not sure if that matters, since this should be related to IIS. What is the difference between MVC3 and MVC4 that is creating this behavior?

Edited:

Here is my config file:

```
 <trust level="Full" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Home/LogOn" timeout="2880" slidingExpiration="true"/>
</authentication>
<sessionState timeout="2880" />
```

Comment: How did you verify it's exactly 5 minutes?  Can you post your session configuration so others can see if there might be an error?  Do you have any special session code in your application?  If so it might be worth showing that relevant code.

Comment: @JustinHelgerson How I tested: I connect, and wait 5 minutes, I am asked to reconnect. Sorry for not posting the config file, please see the update.

Answer (score 0):

hey @MBen you read this article that may help you. 
http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/906b060113-Controlling-Session-Behavior-in-Asp.Net-MVC4.html